# Turning a dynamic script into a static one

Tags: python

I have a script that I'm working on.

It is based on a different script that does the following:

1. Takes the info listed in `players_df`
2. Plugs it into the script to produce a list of all of that users "followers" (in this example, it's only two records)
3. Passes those two records IDs through the `get_bios` function, specifically the `api.user_info(follower_id)['user']['biography']` part, which should produce an output that looks as such when you run `print(bios)`: `[[14479686613, ''], [2897711656, 'PROFILE TEST. ATLANTA.']]`
4. Then assigns them variable names in `print_bios()`

The script looks like this (it will be reproducible if you enter your Instagram credentials in `user_name` and `password` but you can probably answer this without needing that):

```
from ftplib import error_proto
from hashlib import new
from multiprocessing.spawn import import_main_path
from time import sleep
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch
from operator import itemgetter
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from collections import Counter
import datetime
import os.path

user_name = "XXXXX"
password = "XXXXXX"

api = Client(user_name, password)

players = [['cwoods142', '47484241464']]
player_df = pd.DataFrame(players, columns=['username', 'userId'])

def pull_followers(username_instagram, userid_instagram):
    followers = []
    combinacao = []
    results = api.user_followers(userid_instagram, rank_token=api.generate_uuid())
    followers.extend(results.get('users', []))

    next_max_id = results.get('next_max_id')
    
    while next_max_id:
        results = api.user_followers(userid_instagram, rank_token=api.generate_uuid(), max_id=next_max_id)
        followers.extend(results.get('users', []))
        next_max_id = results.get('next_max_id')

    userid = [followers[i]['pk'] for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    
    full_names = [followers[i]['full_name'] for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    
    usernames = [followers[i]['username'] for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    
    profile_pic_url = [followers[i]['profile_pic_url'] for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    
    followers_text = ['follower' for i in range(0,len(followers))]

    following_username = [str(username_instagram) for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    
    following_userid = [str(userid_instagram) for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    
    combinacao.extend([list(i) for i in zip(userid, full_names,
                                            usernames, profile_pic_url, followers_text,
                                            following_username, following_userid)])
    combinacao = sorted(combinacao, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=False)
    return combinacao

all_followers = []

for i in range(len(player_df)):
    all_followers += pull_followers(player_df['username'][i], player_df["userId"][i])

def get_bios(followers):
    bios = []
    for follower in followers:
        follower_id = follower[0]
        bios += [[follower_id, api.user_info(follower_id)['user']['biography']]]
    return bios

bios = get_bios(all_followers)

def print_bios():
    s = ''
    for row in bios:
        s += '\n' + 'user_id: ' + str(row[0]) + ', bio: ' + str(row[1])
    print(s)

print_bios()
```

**What I'm trying to do is rewrite this in a way that cuts out the first part. So the code with the API where you pull the list of followers is no longer needed. Instead, I'm trying to take a static list of usernames and userids and run it. So my attempt looked like this:**

```
    user_name = "XXXXX"
    password = "XXXXX"
    
    api = Client(user_name, password)
    
    all_followers = [['maxtalentllc', '2897711656'], ['fierro5141', '14479686613']]

def get_bios(followers):
    bios = []
    for follower in followers:
        follower_id = follower[0]
        bios += [[follower_id, api.user_info(follower_id)['user']['biography']]]
    return bios

bios = get_bios(all_followers)

def print_bios():
    s = ''
    for row in bios:
        s += '\n' + 'user_id: ' + str(row[0]) + ', bio: ' + str(row[1])
    print(s)
     print_bios()
```

But when I run that I am met with errors which the log can be found below

I know I'm close, but can't quite get over this last error.

**EDIT: Here is the entire error log:**

```
    Error parsing error response: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instagram_private_api/client.py:523, in Client._call_api(self, endpoint, params, query, return_response, unsigned, version)
    522     self.logger.debug('DATA: {0!s}'.format(data))
--> 523     response = self.opener.open(req, timeout=self.timeout)
    524 except compat_urllib_error.HTTPError as e:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py:523, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    522     meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 523     response = meth(req, response)
    525 return response

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py:632, in HTTPErrorProcessor.http_response(self, request, response)
    631 if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 632     response = self.parent.error(
    633         'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    635 return response

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py:561, in OpenerDirector.error(self, proto, *args)
    560 args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 561 return self._call_chain(*args)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py:494, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    493 func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 494 result = func(*args)
    495 if result is not None:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py:641, in HTTPDefaultErrorHandler.http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    640 def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 641     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ClientError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [32], in <cell line: 34>()
     31         bios += [[follower_id, api.user_info(follower_id)['user']['biography']]]
     32     return bios
---> 34 bios = get_bios(all_followers)
     36 def print_bios():
     37     s = ''

Input In [32], in get_bios(followers)
     29 for follower in followers:
     30     follower_id = follower[0]
---> 31     bios += [[follower_id, api.user_info(follower_id)['user']['biography']]]
     32 return bios

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instagram_private_api/endpoints/users.py:17, in UsersEndpointsMixin.user_info(self, user_id)
     10 def user_info(self, user_id):
     11     """
     12     Get user info for a specified user id
     13 
     14     :param user_id:
     15     :return:
     16     """
---> 17     res = self._call_api('users/{user_id!s}/info/'.format(**{'user_id': user_id}))
     18     if self.auto_patch:
     19         ClientCompatPatch.user(res['user'], drop_incompat_keys=self.drop_incompat_keys)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instagram_private_api/client.py:527, in Client._call_api(self, endpoint, params, query, return_response, unsigned, version)
    525     error_response = self._read_response(e)
    526     self.logger.debug('RESPONSE: {0:d} {1!s}'.format(e.code, error_response))
--> 527     ErrorHandler.process(e, error_response)
    529 except (SSLError, timeout, SocketError,
    530         compat_urllib_error.URLError,   # URLError is base of HTTPError
    531         compat_http_client.HTTPException,
    532         ConnectionError) as connection_error:
    533     raise ClientConnectionError('{} {}'.format(
    534         connection_error.__class__.__name__, str(connection_error)))

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instagram_private_api/errors.py:135, in ErrorHandler.process(http_error, error_response)
    131 except ValueError as ve:
    132     # do nothing else, prob can't parse json
    133     logger.warning('Error parsing error response: {}'.format(str(ve)))
--> 135 raise ClientError(error_msg, http_error.code, error_response)

ClientError: Not Found
```

Comment: WHERE do you get that error?  Show us the whole traceback, please.

Comment: My apologies, Tim! I have edited my answer to provide the entire traceback.

Comment: why are you using pandas here at all?

Comment: I'm still very new to Python. If you have a suggestion for how to better optimize it, please free to include it in your answer! I'm more than open to suggestions from people.

Comment: So, in your first version, `all_followers` is a *list*, but in your second version, it is a `pd.DataFrame`, so it definitely will not behave the same when you pass it to `get_bios`. There seems to be no good reason to involve `pandas` here at all, so just get rid of it and use a list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Thanks for the suggestion. How would that look as a final product though?

Comment: probably just `all_followers = [['maxtalentllc', '2897711656'], ['fierro5141', '14479686613']]`? ALthough, the user-names and ids's might be in the reverse order, I can't tell exactly.

Comment: Hmmm I just tried that but I am still getting a similar error. Please check my edited response.

Comment: Nevermind I think I figured it out